# Nullable Type implementation without nullable feature of C#

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

How can we implement a nullable type in C# if we didn't have this feature in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap a native type into a struct (quick example to give you an idea, untested, lots of room for improvement):

```
public struct NullableDouble {
    public bool hasValue = false;
    private double _value;

    public double Value {
        get {
            if (hasValue)
                return _value;
            else
                throw new Exception(...);
        }
        set {
            hasValue = true;
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>Clearly, you won't get the syntactic sugar of newer C# versions, i.e. you have to use `myNullableDouble.hasValue` instead of `myNullableDouble == null`, etc.</strike> (See Andreas' comment.)

Comment: you can use comparison - as long as you override eg. needed operator or implement the correct interface

Answer (score 10):

[Nullable Implementation for prior .NET 2.0](http://nullabletypes.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Nullable is a generic type. Without generics it is not possible to implement a nullable like that and wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, without attaching business rules to existing values in the data type. eg. int.MinValue can be used as a placeholder, but what if you need this value? If you have a rule where all values are positive, it could work, but not as "nullable".